# How to transform one XML document to another?

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an XML file and I want to parse it, but I didn't know how. Our XML import tool does not understand this. This XML has two options group, size and color. I want to separate these groups in the XML.
Is it possible?

I have been trying for two days without success. My XML file codes are below.

Example XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductID>430</ProductID>
        <Barcode>78pyg</Barcode>
        <ProductName>Sony VAIO</ProductName>
        <ProductDesc><![CDATA[Unprecedented power. The next generation of processing technology has arrived. Built into the newest VAIO notebooks lies Intel's latest, most powerful innovation yet]]></ProductDesc>
        <CategoryName><![CDATA[main:sub]]></CategoryName>
        <Price>10.21</Price>        
        <options>
            <grup_name><![CDATA[Color]]></grup_name>
            <values>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[White]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[Black]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>                
            </values>
            <grup_name><![CDATA[Size]]></grup_name>
            <values>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[S]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[M]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
            </values>
        </options>
        <Stock>1000</Stock>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

And this is how the desired output should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductID>430</ProductID>
        <Barcode>78pyg</Barcode>
        <ProductName>Sony VAIO</ProductName>
        <ProductDesc><![CDATA[Unprecedented power. The next generation of processing technology has arrived. Built into the newest VAIO notebooks lies Intel's latest, most powerful innovation yet]]></ProductDesc>
        <CategoryName><![CDATA[main:sub]]></CategoryName>
        <Price>10.21</Price>
        <colors_options>
            <color_grup><![CDATA[Color]]></color_grup>
            <values>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[White]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[Black]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
            </values>
        </colors_options>
        <size_options>
            <grup_name><![CDATA[Size]]></grup_name>
            <values>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[S]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
                <option>
                    <option_name><![CDATA[M]]></option_name>
                    <option_value>1000</option_value>
                </option>
            </values>
        </size_options>
        <Stock>1000</Stock>
    </Product>
</Products>
```

How can I change with separated options XML file?

Comment: what is your xml tool? how do you try to parse this file?

Comment: Try to add some details about how you tried to parse, and what failed. Add an explanation of what you expect as a result, so we don't have to guess from your example snippet. Looks like you are trying to do a _transform_ from one XML schema to another. If that is the case, XSLT may be a good keyword for Google.